# Find nearest lines to large number of points in an oracle spatial database

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial

The problem I have is simple:

I have a set of datasets. Each dataset has within it a set of points. Each set of points is an identical a 6km spaced grid (this grid never changes). Each point has an associated value.Each dataset is unrelated, so the problem can be seen as just a single set of points.

If the value of a point exceeds a predefined threshold value then the point has to be queried against an oracle spatial database to find all line segments within a certain distance of the point.

Which is a simple enough problem to solve.

The line segments have a non-unique ID, which allow them to be grouped together into features of size 1 to 700 segments (it's all predefined topology).

Ultimately I need to know which feature IDs match against which points as well as the number of line segments for each feature match against each point.

In terms of dataset sizes:

- There are around 200 datasets.
- There are 56,000 points per dataset.
- There is a little over 180,000 line segments in the spatially indexed database.
- The line segments can be grouped into a total of 1900 features.
- Usually there aren't many more than in the order of 10^3 points that exceed the threshold per dataset.

---

I have created a solution and it works adequately,
however I'm unhappy with the overall run times - it takes around 3min per dataset.

Normally I wouldn't mind if a precomputation task takes that long, but due to constraints this task cannot take more than an hour to run, and ideally would only take 1/2 an hour.

Currently I use SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE to do the query, and I run this query for each and every point that exceeds the threshold:

```
SELECT id, count(shape) AS segments, sum(length) AS length
FROM (
        SELECT shape, id, length
        FROM lines_1
    UNION ALL
        SELECT shape, id, length
        FROM lines_2
)
WHERE SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE(
    shape,
    sdo_geometry(
        3001,
        8307,
        SDO_POINT_TYPE(:lng,:lat, 0),
        null,
        null
    ),
    'distance=4 unit=km'
) = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY id
```

This query takes around 0.4s to execute, which isn't all that bad, but it adds up for a single dataset, and is compounded over all of the datasets.

I am not overly experienced with Oracle spatial databases, so I'm not sure how to improve the speed.

Note that I cannot change the format of the incoming set of points, nor can I change the format of the database.

The only way to speed it up that I can think of is by pre computing the query for each point and storing that in a separate table, but I'd rather not do that as it more or less creates another copy of the data.

So the question is - is there a better way to do query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up precomputing my query into the following table.

```
+---------+---------+
| LINE_ID | VARCHAR |
| LAT     | FLOAT   |
| LNG     | FLOAT   |
+---------+---------+
```

There were just too many multiline segments for it to be efficient.

By precomputing it I can just lookup in the table for the relevant IDs (which ultimately was all I cared about).

The query takes less than 1/10th of the time, so it works out a lot faster.

Ultimately the tradeoff of having to recompute the point to ID mapping every week (takes about 2 hours) was worth the speed up.